# Amazon MWS API to update inventory

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

Please do help me out for updating Amazon inventory through API.

My case is, If I update inventory through feeds, it is taking little long, 10 min, 15 min some time it is taking more then hour also.

Problem is if I update inventory now, it will take 10 min, In that 10 min any order got placed then the quantity updated will go wrong. so how to handle this scenario.

please do help us for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We were updating inventory every few minutes around the clock.  A sync job that I wrote determines inventory changes constantly in our system and then every 5 minutes, creates a new inventory feed.  The feeds don't take long to process since they are small and if there is an order in the meantime, then no problem because it will be picked up again in a few minutes.   I would think in small chunks continuously, and not in large batches.  Hope that helps...we pushed through lots of data over the years.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you do not mind, can you just share the code how you handled.

Comment: are you using the MWS C# Client Library? https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090101/cSharp.html/139-3860472-8356909   You basically want to submit a feed, check it for completion, then send another one, all within a loop until your list of updates is complete.  In my case, I used a windows service on a 5 or 10 minute timer, but it could be done in a number of ways, service, an API endpoint, AWS Lambda, etc. etc

Comment: Can you confirm if you had to have a sellers account and register as a developer to do this? Or can you just produce API keys from an existing account and link to it?